# Error while configuring a AMediaCodec decoder instance on Samsung S9+

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I need help on Samsung S9+. All I am trying to do is to create a decoder and subsequently configure it to render to a surface. The configure step is failing. See the code and logs below.

Am I going wrong with the color format? This code is working fine on other devices, but not on Samsung S9+. I tried giving it the following value but to no avail:

COLOR_FormatSurface

Added in API level 18
public static final int COLOR_FormatSurface

Constant Value: 2130708361 (0x7f000789)

```
void func(AMediaFormat* mediaFormat, ANativeWindow* surface)
{
    // ...

    AMediaFormat_getString(mediaFormat, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_MIME, &mime);
    AMediaCodec *videoDecoder = AMediaCodec_createDecoderByType(mime);

    // this step is failing
    media_status_t status = AMediaCodec_configure(videoDecoder, mediaFormat, surface, NULL, 0);

    // ...
}
```

````
2019-04-02 11:25:48.578 999-17684/? E/OMX-VDEC-1080P: Unsupported output color format for c2d (2141391876)
2019-04-02 11:25:48.578 999-17684/? E/OMX-VDEC-1080P: Setting color format failed
2019-04-02 11:25:48.606 999-17684/? E/OMX-VDEC-1080P: Unsupported output color format for c2d (2141391876)
2019-04-02 11:25:48.606 999-17684/? E/OMX-VDEC-1080P: Setting color format failed
2019-04-02 11:25:48.613 15598-18889 E/NdkMediaCodec: configure: err(-5001), failed with format: AMessage(what = 0x00000000) = {
      string mime = "video/avc"
      int64_t durationUs = 91604722
      int32_t isDMCMMExtractor = 1
      int32_t track-id = 1
      string language = "```"
      int32_t width = 3840
      int32_t height = 2160
      int32_t display-width = 3840
      int32_t display-height = 2160
      int32_t color-range = 2
      int32_t color-standard = 6
      int32_t color-transfer = 3
      int32_t max-input-size = 6291456
      int32_t frame-rate = 30
      int32_t profile = 8
      int32_t level = 32768
      Buffer csd-0 = {
        00000000:  00 00 00 01 67 64 00 33  ac d2 00 f0 01 0f a5 60  ....gd.3.......`
        00000010:  c0 c0 c0 da 14 26 a0                              .....&.
      }
      Buffer csd-1 = {
        00000000:  00 00 00 01 68 ee 06 e2  c0                       ....h....
      }
      int32_t color-format = 2130708361
      RefBase *native-window = 0x73221a0000
    }
````